# What is wrong with this conditional proof of P=NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

I have recently thought up the following proof that L=P implies P=NP.

> Suppose L=P. Let A be a problem in NP. By the verifier definition of NP, each positive solution to A has a witness that can be verified in polynomial time. Since P=L, the same solution can be verified in logarithmic space. Thus NP=NL. But then NL is contained in P, which means that NP is contained in P and therefore P=NP.

By the efficient market hypothesis, I suspect this proof is flawed. I am however unable to determine the exact nature of the error. Can someone point it out?

Answer (score 11):

> Suppose L=P. Let A be a problem in NP. By the verifier definition of NP, each positive solution to A has a witness that can be verified in polynomial time. Since P=L, the same solution can be verified in logarithmic space. Thus NP=NL.

You haven't shown that **NP$\,=\,$NL**. The only method you've derived to show that $x\in A$, is to nondeterministically "guess" a witness $y$ and use the deterministic logspace algorithm to verify it. However, $y$ itself may be polynomially long, whereas your **NL** machine can only guess logarithmically many bits: your **NL** machine doesn't have enough space to store the witness, so you don't have an **NL** algorithm.

Also, note that we already know that witnesses to **NP**-complete problems can be verified in a complexity class smaller than **L**. [Fagin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagin%27s_theorem) says that **NP** is exactly the set of problems that can be defined in the existential fragment of second-order logic. This is equivalent to saying that you can verify a polynomial-length witness using first-order logic. **FO** is strictly weaker than **L**, since first-order logic can't solve simple logspace problems like telling you if your witness string contains an even number of $1$s.